# Parsing nf_conntrack struct

Tags: c++, netfilter

I'm trying to use libnetfilter_conntrack to monitor network activity.

All I could find is [this](https://github.com/threatstack/libnetfilter_conntrack/blob/master/examples/nfct-mnl-event.c) example.

I would like to be able to extract the data from the nf_conntrack struct and the only way that I could find is using nfct_snprintf and then parse the buffer.

I want to store the data in a struct like this:

```
struct connection_details {
    std::string src_ip;
    int src_port;
    std::string dst_ip;
    int dst_port;
    std::string type;
    std::string state;
};
```

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this for the others who end up here, you cannot really parse the struct nf_conntrack object directly because of the abstractions implemented by the library.

you can however include the header file from the library source code libnetfilter_conntrack/include/internal/object.h to access the nf_conntrack object directly, be careful though, there is a reason why abstractions are present.